# Supporting Multilanguage Android 6.0.1 is revoking language options menu in order to choose language in every page

Tags: java, android, localization, android-resources, multilingual

I am developing an Android app which is supporting more than one language. I have created resource files like indicated in web page of Android Developer. I am having this on API 23 general As you can see from the picture: [Android Resource File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpzRe.png)

When user selects the Language and when I try to set the language at next page choosing Language option is revoked and even when I choose English or Turkish It won't go. You can find example screen shots:

Since my membership on Stackoverflow is new I cannot not add more than 2 links.

[Choose Language Options Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwX6n.png)

So here is my code for setting language:

```
  ImageButton turkishButton;
    ImageButton englishButton;
    ImageButton russianButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        turkishButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.turkish_button);
        englishButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.english_button);
        russianButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.russian_button);

        turkishButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        englishButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        russianButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.english_button:
                setLocale("en");
                break;

            case R.id.turkish_button:
                setLocale("tr");
                break;

            case R.id.russian_button:
                setLocale("ru");
                break;

        }

    }

    public void setLocale(String lang) {

        Locale  myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        Intent refresh = new Intent(this, AppCollectionViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(refresh);
    }
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:configChanges="locale">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MainMenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.AppCollectionViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/main_menu"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActivity"
            />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MainBranchListActivity"
            android:label="@string/nearby_branches"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.BranchesInfoActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActivity"

            />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.OperationTypeActivity"
            android:label="@string/operation_type"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActivity"
            />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.TicketActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActivity"

            />
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Any help will be happy. Thanks in advance